# VBA Code Isn't "holding" ThisWorksheet Parameter

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros

I want to retrieve one column of values from another workbook and populate a tab in my current workbook. This will ultimately go into a much longer module I've written that works great. I just wanted this step automated.  Below is the code.

I get a *subscript out of range* error at the paste line. It seems as if my statement setting `currentWb` to `ThisWorkbook` isn't working because the second workbook being copied from is still open, the range selected and copied and just waiting for a destination to paste.  I've searched and tried everything I can think of.

```
Sub OpenWorkbookToPullData()

Dim sUserInput As String
    sUserInput = InputBox("Enter Account Folder Name:", "Folder Name")

Dim path As String
    path = "C:\users\" & Environ$("username") & "\OneDrive\Documents\Brightree\" & sUserInput & "\Financial Scorecard\Exceptions.xlsm"

Dim currentWb As Workbook
    Set currentWb = ThisWorkbook

Dim exceptionWb As Workbook
    Set exceptionWb = Workbooks.Open(path)

Dim exceptionWs As Worksheet
    Set exceptionWs = exceptionWb.Sheets("Exceptions")

Dim rng_data As Range
    Set rng_data = exceptionWs.Range("A1:A20")

 rng_data.Copy
 currentWb.Sheets("Exception").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

exceptionWb.Close (False)

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you stepped through it (F8) to see that your variables are all getting defined properly? [your error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264519(v=vs.60).aspx) indicates you're referencing something that doesn't exist. Since you are opening the second wb properly and copying the range, this would suggest the issue is in currentWB, since exceptionwb.close doesn't execute.

Comment: I know that if I skip that line, the close command executes and closes the exceptionWb.  I'm with you - I believe it's something with the currentWB variable - almost like it forgets that it's been set to ThisWorkbook.  But stepping through, can I see what each variable's value is?  As much as I've done in VBA, I haven't had to do that yet!!  Thank you!!

Comment: Just hover over the variable once it's assigned, it will tell you what its value is

Answer (score 1):

You must insure that *Sheets("Exceptions")* exists in **both** workbooks.
And as **Twisty** points out; check the spelling of the worksheet names.

Comment: In other words @LeAnn Smith Scott, your code refers to the name **Exceptions** in the source workbook, but **Exception** (no trailing `S`) in the destination workbook.

Comment: It actually is different in each workbook - trying that now - thanks so much!  I'll update!!

Comment: Well, I made every reference to the word Exception singular - still got the error.  I even thought maybe since my first workbook wasn't saved as a macro enabled workbook that might be it so tried that with no luck as well.